# doesnt remove cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableView` that allows the user to select multiple images. The problem is that my delete method isnt working.

I keep track of all the selected images and when the user confirms a delete then the images are removed from the array and the table should update.

The call to `[self.tableview reloadData]` is not removing the cells from my tableView.

How can I achieve this? How can I call

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

or something similar to force the table to check the data source and redraw the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the scenario , you can perform this thing in 2 ways

1)using reloadData function

```
while using this please make sure about the 2 thing when you choose to delete the cell first check whether that particular record has been deleted at indexpath which you want it to be.
```

Secondly once data is deleted from array after that use [self.tableView reloadData] or [ObjectofTableView reloadData]. This way also works fine.

But apple has provided some methods to remove the cells from the table with some effects.So it's much use this below way.

2)Way I will prefer you to use this since it looks great in app with UITableView.

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:
  (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

  ```
   //Over  here first delete record from array at indexPath
  ```

  //[self makeLogout];
  [self.acloginTblView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  }

  [self.acloginTblView reloadData];
  }

Hope After giving so much pain to my finger will solve your queries in better way ;)

Comment: HI, thanks for the help, but I am checking the data source of ALAssets for items that match items in another array which tracks the selected ALAssets, and the issue was that The assets in the selection array where subview overlays which detected tapGestures, rather than the ALAsset linked to this overlay. :( but I solved it now, and the reloadData works.  thanks for the time, your fingers can have pain, your a programmer ;)

Comment: Was way to much effort to link a dictionary of ALAssets to their Cell indexes via the overlay tapRecognizer which needed to be recomputed every time a deletion occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
[yourTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it requires implementation of a `UITableViewDelegate` method to use red accessory button `DELETE`
Also, make sure to update the data source `before` doing any inserting or deleting. If the count of rows provided by the data source doesn't match the count of rows in table after inserting or deleting, crash will occur.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Update data source to match row counts of the source and the tableView

        // An array containing multiple NSIndexPath is used
        // You can create an array with only one element
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
}
```